# Sum of numbers on dice using stars and bars

Tags: probability, combinatorics, diophantine-equations, dice

I derived a general result about the sum of numbers on a die whose correctness I was wondering about, so could someone please confirm it? It is as follows:

If $k$ dice are thrown, and the sum we desire is $n$,
we are looking for positive integer solutions to $$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n$$ with each $x_i$ satisfying $1 \leq x_i \leq 6$. This can be found by calculating the positive integer solutions without the restrictions, which will be $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$. If $n \geq 6 + k$, we will need to subtract the number of positive solutions to $$(y_1 + 6) + (y_2 + 6) + \cdots + (y_k + 6) = n$$
$$y_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_k = n - 6k$$ which will be $\binom{n-6k-1}{k-1}$.

Therefore the final answer is $$\binom{n-1}{k-1} - \binom{n-6k-1}{k-1}$$

Comment: Have you checked that for any actual examples?  For instance, with $k=2,n=12$ we know the answer is $1$ but your expression is undefined.  For $k=2,n=14$ the true answer is $0$ but your answer is $1$.  Always check examples.

Comment: Have you give it a sanity check yet?

Comment: You should have defined $y_k:=x_k-5$ so $y_k\ge 1$.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you. I forgot to think of the case where any number of $x_i$ could be greater than 6, not just all. I'll be sure to check for sanity here on out :p.
And also it seems I made an incorrect substitution